# I keep on getting errors while trying to run my java spring boot server

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I've been trying to run the spring boot project that me and my friends were working on as a team but every time I try to run the project on my system I keep on getting these errors

```java
2024-01-18T19:33:59.151+03:30 ERROR 12916 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2024-01-18T19:33:59.155+03:30  WARN 12916 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2024-01-18T19:33:59.168+03:30  WARN 12916 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-01-18T19:34:00.718+03:30 ERROR 12916 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2024-01-18T19:34:00.718+03:30 ERROR 12916 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-18T19:34:00.748+03:30 ERROR 12916 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

I tried to re-install the packages or even download the project and run it again but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: "re-run your application with 'debug' enabled" and you will find what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current choice of property with for postgreSQLDialect with ‘org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect’  .
The information is recorded in the Javadoc for PostgreSQLDialect .
The usage of this has been deprecated. Instead, use PostgreSQL82Dialect.